# Is Image Processing Toolbox enough?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am going to start working on project in which I have to do image processing on a MATLAB and convert it C through automated code generation and then to a microcontroller to solve a puzzle , I am going to start learning image processing on MATLAB now the question is that I already have image processing toolbox in MATLAB will i be needing some other toolbox for that or just image processing toolbox is enough ? as i have to tell my university in advance for all the requirements

Comment: Image Processing is a subset of Signal Processing, so you should probably have the Signal Processing Toolbox installed as well.  Also, the Computer Vision Toolbox is something to think about if you want to take your learning to the next level.

Comment: Thanks alot ill check the computer vision toolbox!

Comment: To convert MATLAB to C code, you'll need MATLAB Coder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion Image Processing Toolbox and Computer Vision System Toolbox  will solve most of your problems. But again, it completely depends on your problem statement.

If the problem is too complex or if it requires machine learning then you might require Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox or Neural Network Toolbox. If you are acquiring images from external hardware like a 'webcam' then you might also need Image Acquisition Toolbox.

Comment: Yes i will be reading images from webcam connected to my microcontroller , thanks

Comment: I'm not sure you can use the Image Acquisition Toolbox with Coder to create C-code for a microcontroller... But for testing purposes (on the computer) it is perfectly fine.

Comment: I just checked it says in the key features "Support for C code generation in Simulink" so i guess it does maybe